# How to call custom field on Taxonomy from category wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I done insert below code to function.php, but can't call data by using shortcode.

```
function productcat_add_form_fields(){
    echo '<div class="form-field">
        <label for="cct_pdf_url">File PDF Download URL</label>
        <input name="cct_pdf_url" id="cct_pdf_url" type="text" value="">
        <p id="cct_pdf_url-description">A url to a map that shows the neighborhood.</p>
        </div>';  
}

function save_productcat_meta($term_id){
    if(!isset($_POST['cct_pdf_url'])){ return; }
  
    update_term_meta( $term_id, 'cct_pdf_url', sanitize_url( $_POST['cct_pdf_url'] ));
}

function productcat_edit_form_fields($term) { 
    $url = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'cct_pdf_url', true );
    echo '<tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="up_more_info_url">File PDF Download URL</label></th>
        <td><input name="cct_pdf_url" id="cct_pdf_url" type="text" value="'.$url.'">
        <p class="description">A url to a map that shows the neighborhood.</p></td>
    </tr>';
}

add_action('productcat_add_form_fields', 'productcat_add_form_fields');
add_action('productcat_edit_form_fields', 'productcat_edit_form_fields');

add_action('create_productcat', 'save_productcat_meta');
add_action('edited_productcat', 'save_productcat_meta');
```

I try using several shortcode below :

[wpbb post:cct_pdf_url taxonomy="productcat"]

[wpbb post:meta_box field='cct_pdf_url']

[wpbb archive:productcat key='cct_pdf_url']

[wpbb post:custom_field key='cct_pdf_url']